# excel two different color gradient within same column

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

Is it possible to fill a column in red and green so that the values above a certain number (e.g. 1000) are highlighted in a gradient of red and the ones below the number are highlighted in a gradient of green?

Comment: Closest you will get is a three color gradient with white as the middle set on number 1000

Answer (score 2):

Use a 3-Color-Scale with white as the middle color and number set at 1000:

[image]