# A profit statement has to have a gradient of green for the profit and a gradient of red for loss

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[excel two different color gradient within same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037022/excel-two-different-color-gradient-within-same-column)

I did check out the link above. However, when the range becomes big, the values close to the middle are colored white. I would like them to be light green immediately above the median and light red immediately below. Is there any way to make this happen in excel? Two color gradients in the same column?

Comment: This is not about programming, but how to use Excel in general. Please take it to SuperUser.com.

Comment: Okay, I shall. Thank you.